# Wrong feed redirection

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, redirection

I'm watching a problem with the URLs of your feeds:

I was using http://www.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/django instead https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/django and I got a redirection to a domain hosted on a mysterious comfeeds TLD

```
$ curl http://www.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/django
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://stackoverflow.comfeeds/tag/django">here</a></body>
```

Comment: Seems to be a slash missing ...

Comment: Confirmed. Redirect from www.stackoverflow.com eats the slash after *com*, no matter what else is coming after that.

Answer (score 1):

Good catch - this is fixed and will be deployed later this evening.